# Android/Java: Small server for control msg and image transfer: Two competing listensocket.accept() destroying for each other

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I am creating a system that sends both control info (using REST, retrofit, okhttp) and then data images of size > 1MB. Both devices are Android devices, one as "multi" server, one as "multi" client. Since the ip is the same, I have different port numbers for these two connections. Later, more client devices will create an even worse situation!

These two connections works perfectly as long as only one of them are used, but as a REST control msg is sent, a series of images could be sent in an immediate fashion, i.e. the control message (from client!) is "I have changed config, please be prepared for a series of images as a result". Most of the time, this works, but there is a vulnerability for the first image sent (socked is closed), and thereafter more occassionally the same happens.

Question: Is there a smarter way than I am aware of to coordinate and "queue" these two socket streams so that they will "almost never" destroy for each other? To be precise, it is the REST control messages (from client) that causes IO exceptions in the image connection (also from client). Here is my code, where I start the REST server in the first round of the loop because it will always be alive, and then I listen.accept for image transfer request, which are erratic.

It was done like this so as to start both these two servers from the same runnable, being hopeful that would solve the scheduling problem, but in vain. So, how to do this, I have not found any examples of a multiserver (as I call it) that does several listensocket.accept in paralell.

I suppose I could use okhttp to send both rest commands and images, but shouldnt it be possible to handle two serversockets on one device?

The runnable is starting out from UI thread. Both HttpRestServer and ImageFileServer are of type class ... extends Thread. The ImageFileServer closes everything after each image received. It also receives the filename of the image via the writeUTF feature. Working fine.

Thanks for any advice. I am hoping for some teaspoon instructions and code example. Thanks!

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){


                   if(httpRestServer == null) {
                       httpRestServer = new HttpRestServer(restServerSocket, restServerPort);
                       httpRestServer.start();
                    }

            //keep on receiving files
            while (!ceaseOperation) {
                try {
                   

                   //Wait here for incoming clients, a new Thread per call in this solution
                    new ImageDataServer(imageServerSocket.accept(), deviceNameAsFolderName).start();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    imageSuccess = false;
                    Log.e(TAG, "ERROR Image not received. Skipped, from: " + deviceNameAsFolderName + s + e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            
            try { //operation ceased
                clientSocket.close();
                imageServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```